# replace missing values or characters with the particular row mean in R

Tags: r, replace

I want to replace missing values or character values in a data with the row mean. for example in the data below, the missing values are denoted with "U" and I want to replace all the "U" from p1 to p6 with the values in the "ave" column for each row. There are thousands of the rows to replace.

```
num p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6   ave

L1  0  10 1  U  0  -10   1.3

L2  10  1 10 10 U  10    7.1

L3  U  10 10  U 1  -10   3.1
```

Comment: You should add a tag corresponding to the language you are using (R?).

Comment: Yeah - without info on what language you are using it's hard to help.

Comment: Can you `dput` a few lines of your actual data. Is the "ave" column part of your data frame? Are there *both* missing values and characters like "U" representing missing values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
mydf <- read.table(
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
  text = "num p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6   ave
          L1  0  10 1  U  0  -10   1.3
          L2  10  1 10 10 U  10    7.1
          L3  U  10 10  U 1  -10   3.1")

cbind(mydf[1], 
      t(apply(mydf[-1], 1, 
              function(x) ifelse(x == "U", x["ave"], x))))
#   num  p1 p2 p3  p4  p5  p6 ave
# 1  L1   0 10  1 1.3   0 -10 1.3
# 2  L2  10  1 10  10 7.1  10 7.1
# 3  L3 3.1 10 10 3.1   1 -10 3.1
```

Comment: the file is in a .csv but R changes the "U" to NA, how would it work with the NA?

Comment: Replace `ifelse(x == "U"...` with `ifelse(is.na(x)...`

Answer (score 1):

The data:

```
df<-read.table(text="num p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6   ave
L1  0  10 1  U  0  -10   1.3
L2  10  1 10 10 U  10    7.1
L3  U  10 10  U 1  -10   3.1  ", header = TRUE)
```

You could use `apply` to replace the `U`s:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) replace(x, x == "U", tail(x, 1)))))

  num  p1 p2 p3  p4  p5  p6 ave
1  L1   0 10  1 1.3   0 -10 1.3
2  L2  10  1 10  10 7.1  10 7.1
3  L3 3.1 10 10 3.1   1 -10 3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

for loops are generally discouraged in the r language so sven's answer is better, but here's a straightforward way to do what you're trying to do..

```
# example data table
mtcars

# here's how to access all the columns below two in the first row
mtcars[ 1 ,  mtcars[ 1 , ] < 2 ]

# here's how to take the mean of all columns at or above two in the first row
rowMeans( mtcars[ 1 ,  mtcars[ 1 , ] >= 2 ] , na.rm = T )

# here's how to overwrite the values below two with the mean of all columns at or above two
mtcars[ 1 ,  mtcars[ 1 , ] < 2 ] <- rowMeans( mtcars[ 1 ,  mtcars[ 1 , ] >= 2 ] , na.rm = T )


# run this command for every row, and you're done
for ( i in seq( nrow( mtcars ) ) ){
    mtcars[ i ,  mtcars[ i , ] < 2 ] <- 
        rowMeans( mtcars[ i ,  mtcars[ i , ] >= 2 ] , na.rm = T )
}
```